# convert annotated documents to UIMA xml format to import in IBM Watson

Tags: xml, watson, uima

I have a bunch of annotated text files generated by Dedoose Qualitative Analysis Software.

I am trying to import them in IBM Watson but it requires UIMA CAS XML format. I can convert to XML but I don't know how to use UIMA. They are already annotated. I am not trying to make a new annotator. IBMs documentation is not helping either. Please help. I have been stuck on this for a quite a while.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing which IBM software you're talking about is hard to help you, but I worked with the Watson Content Analytics

You should check the tool you are using if it provides any support to export the annotated text to an UIMA CAS format (xmi for example) or if you can export this annotator (of Dedoose) as a PEAR file so you can add it in a UIMA pipeline